# Issues implementing interface methods

Tags: c#, interface

I'm using interfaces for the first time in my Unity project. I am trying to get this clas to implement the Move() method. Should be easy, but Its not working. I've tried all the Microsoft pages and some similar questions but haven't found the same issue.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public interface IMover {

     float Move();

}

public class Move_1 : Mover {

public float moveSpeed = 1;
public float energyConsumption = 0.1;

float Move(Vector2 vec,Rigidbody2D rb){
    rb.AddForce (vec * moveSpeed);
    return energyConsumption * vec.magnitude;
}

}
```

I'm sure I've missed something obvious. I've tried `IMover.Move()` and things like

```
public float Mover(
```

but nothing is working. On a side not, I'm a little confused about the visibility modifiers with interfaces. The interfaces don't have a visibility modifier so I assumed it would be part of the implementation. I'm probably confusing implicit and explicit declarations.

Comment: try Move_1 : IMover rather than Move_1 : Mover

Comment: The signature of the method has to be the same in the interface and the implementing class. Second, unless you're using explicit interface implementation (`float IMover.Move() { ... }`), the method *has* to be `public`. Reversely, if you're using explicit implementation, it has to be `private`. The interface members don't need an accessibility modifier, because the only one that really makes sense is `public`. If you want to restrict accessibility, you have to apply it to the whole interface.

Answer (score 1):

Your interface defined one method

```
public interface IMover
{
    float Move();
}
```

This means any class implementing this interface must have a public method called Move with no parameters and that returns `float`

```
public class SomeClass : IMover
{
    public float Move()
    {
        // some code
        return someFloat;
    }
}
```

Your class as you have it does not implement the interface, though this may be a typo.

You can happily create a method overload in your class, but you must also have the signature defined in the interface so the following is valid

```
public class SomeClass : IMover
{
    public float Move() { /* implement */ }

    public float Move(float f) { /* implement */ }
}
```

However the following (which is similar to your situation) is invalid as it does not have the method defined by the contract of the interface `IMover`

```
public class SomeClass : IMover
{
    public float Move(float f) { /* implement */ }
}
```

---

As per your comment, what you need to do is to modify your interface thusly:

```
public interface IMover
{
    float Move(Vector2 vec, Rigidbody2D rb);
}
```

and make sure your declare the method as public in your class.

Comment: Yeah it was a typo, but that isn't the issue. I plan on having every Move method to take a float and a rigidbody. Can I change the interface to reflect this? 'public interface IMover {

 float Move(Vector2 vec,Rigidbody2D rb);

}' Will this solve my issue? it apparently is still not implementing.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public interface IMover {

     float Move();

}

public class Move_1 : IMover {

    private Vector2 vec;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    public float moveSpeed = 1;
    public float energyConsumption = 0.1;

    public Move_1(Vector2 vec,Rigidbody2D rb){
        this.vec = vec;
        this.rb = rb;
    }

    float Move(){
        this.rb.AddForce (this.vec * moveSpeed);
        return energyConsumption * vec.magnitude;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is this constructor for? I don't really understand, sorry.

Comment: Your interface has no arguments, so you cannot pass an argument into the class's method. When implementing an interface's methods you must adhere to the signature of the original method. Since your "Move" function requires the vec and rb parameters, I put them into a constructor.